# Iterate over multiple generators (file handles)

Tags: python, file, generator

What is the best way to read a line from multiple files at once (iterate over multiple generators).

My attempt:

```
files = ['a.dat', 'b.dat', 'c.dat']
fHandles = [open(file, 'r') for file in files]
for line in zip(*fHandles):
    print line[0]
    print line[1]
    print line[2]
```

Is there a better way to do it?

(I feel like `zip(*fHandles)` is a bit funny...)

Comment: `zip` will eagerly read the entire content of all files so is not memory efficient. Given the fact that the number of lines of each file may not be same, I'd recommend you to use `itertools.izip_longest` if you want to iterate over them at the same time. Also, don't forget to close them after you are done with them.

Comment: @ozgur I think you should expand that into an answer :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didn't realise that `zip` would read the whole file.

Comment: To be strict, a file is not a generator. It is an iterator. Generators are iterators as well, but is constructed in a completely different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zip` will eagerly read the entire content of all files so is not memory efficient. Given the fact that the number of lines of each file may also be different, I'd recommend you to use `itertools.izip_longest` if you want to iterate over the lines at the same time.

```
import itertools

files = ['a.dat', 'b.dat', 'c.dat']
handles = [open(file, 'r') for file in files]

for a, b, c in itertools.izip_longest(*handles, fillvalue=''):
    print a
    print b
    print c
```

Also, don't forget to close files after you are done with them.

```
for handle in handles:
    handle.close()
```

Comment: `[handle.close() for handle in handles]` would be abusing the list comprehension. `for handle in handles: handle.close()` is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure how to quantify best, but this should read line by line and group the results.

```
# Files to load
files = ['a.dat', 'b.dat', 'c.dat']

# Number of lines to read from each
lines = 3

# Open the files
fhs = [open(f) for f in files]

# Read x number of lines from each
print([map(lambda f: f.readline(), fhs) for x in range(lines)])

# Close the handles
[fh.close() for fh in fhs]
```

Produced:

```
[['line1', 'line1', 'line1'], ['line2', 'line2', 'line2'], ['line3', 'line3', 'line3']]
```

If they have unequal lines (say b and c only have 2 lines, but a has 3), it produces:

```
[['line1', 'line1', 'line1'], ['line2', 'line2', 'line2'], ['line3', '', '']]
```

Comment: Will this work if the files consist of unequal number of lines ..?

Comment: Depends, I'm not sure what the overall intention of the original poster is. In the case of unequal lines, the above code returns '' for the file which did not contain any further lines. I edited to show the results I got.